# Making the title of a directory the date in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-11.04

I want to make the current date into the title of a directory in `/home/chris/Downloads` by using `mkdir` and `date -I`

I tried
    mkdir "date -I"
that gets me a folder *named* "date -I" Without the quotes it gives the error

```
mkdir: invalid option -- 'I'
```

Trying to make it a variable next

```
date= date -I
mkdir -p $date
```

with the `-p` option, it looked good, but upon inspection, the folder wasn't created.
removing `-p` gets me the error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/chris/Downloads/': File exists
```

and even pointing it to the entire path

```
date= date -I
mkdir "/home/chris/Downloads/$date"
```

gets me the same error as before

It's not that the variable is empty, I echo'd it and the value is what I should expect, it seems to be that the value isn't substituted before the directory is created. What would be the way to get around this problem? I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) if that gives you any more info.

Comment: The solution doesn't require setting a `$date` variable, but your syntax for doing so is off, and not just because of the missing backticks or $(...).  In a variable assignment, you can't have spaces either before or after the `=`.  `date= date -I` sets `$date` to the empty string, and then runs `date -I`.  It's just like `date=foobar date -I` except that `$date` is set to the empty string rather than to `foobar`.  The correct syntax would be `date=$(date -I)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong:

```
mkdir -p /home/chris/downloads/$(date -I)
```

or

```
mkdir -p /home/chris/downloads/`date -I`
```

will work

Comment: +1.  Although as a habit, I would suggest putting quotes around shell variable expansions: `mkdir -p /tmp/"$(date -I)"`.  Obivously does not matter for `date`, but for other commands it can.  `mkdir -p /tmp/$(echo foo bar)` does not do what you might expect.

Comment: Also prefer `$( )` over backticks as all POSIX shells support it, it can be nested unlike backticks, and is just easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Use this: backticks run the command instead of printing it out.

```
mkdir `date -I`
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also try xargs (however, not sure if it's a good practice)

```
date -I | xargs mkdir
```